# Find and Replace multiple values form a string and replace with a word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking into creating a macro that would search for a set of many king o texts variations and change it to something else.
For examples:

Find a paragraph followed by the word Art1, Art1., etc  = ˆpArt1, ˆpArt1., ˆpArt 1, ˆpArt I, so on... replace with the string ˆpArt. 1. in bold.

So basically, I have many variations of an occurrence that I need to change so a specific text, and I would be constantly feeding this string to look for many variations on the search to replace with something I would define.

Any ideias?

this is what I'm trying with no success:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    
Dim Arts1 As String

Arts1 = Split(("^p1o", "^p1 o")
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = Arts1
        .Replacement.Text = "^pArtigo 1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: just added what I tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `.replace` function for the string.

```
"^pArt1 Art1".replace("Art1", "TODO")
```

Comment: That code won't do what the OP asks for, especially the bolding part...